# How many ways can a number be written as a sum of two non negative integers?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways can a  number be written as a sum of two non negative integers?

For example there is $4$ way for $7$.   $ 7=0+7=1+6=2+5=3+4$

I think  there is $[ \frac{N}{2}]+1$ way for number$N$. Is it true?

Comment: Your example shows your rule does not work.  Also $0$ is not positive so $0+7$ should not count.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, yes. I forgot to divide by 2. And I use nonnegative numbers. Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider 3+4 and 4+3 as two different ways then yes it will be N+1. Think of it as placing a partition in a row of N objects you can place it right in the beginning, right at the end and any of the N-1 locations. However if 3+4 and 4+3 are considered same then we have only 4 ways of writing 7 as sum of two numbers. In this case the answer will be ceil((N+1)/2) where ceil(x) is smallest integer greater is Han or equal to x.

Comment: No, because we are talking of positive integers.  $0$ is not allowed.  You have a typo with Han at the end.

Comment: Yes I have requested an edit in question changing positive to negative. As seen in example 0+7 is seen as a valid breakup

Comment: Thanks for correcting that was a typo I will edit