# Why is addition non-reversible?

Tags: group-theory

This is an extremely elementary question but I want to make sure I understand this right.

If someone adds two numbers in their mind and tells us the sum, it is impossible to prove mathematically what two numbers they chose (in most cases). The number of distinct ways to add two numbers to form say, an integer $n$, is something like $ceil((N+1)/2)$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3034937/how-many-ways-can-a-number-be-written-as-a-sum-of-two-non-negative-integers)). This shows us that there is more than one way, for any number from 2 and beyond.

I think I am thinking about a function mapping each pair of elements to its sum, and observing that it is not injective.

I am just trying to understand why. As integers are sort of the conceptual basis for the concept of a group (I think), is the fact that different elements can combine to form the same element a result of "closure", in that, when we look at the Cayley table of a group, we will see each element of the group exactly once? So is it a necessary condition on any group that the function (x, y) -> (x + y) can not be bijective? Or is there any relationship between groups cycles and elements having unique composition?

Maybe I am completely off-track here but I am trying to ask the fundamental question of why addition is not reversible and what kind of related structure does on the other hand have that property. What deep difference in structure or properties do they have, allowing this?

Comment: I think an example is helpful. If you take $n=5$, then $1+4=2+3=0$, so this shows clearly, why it can't be "injective". The reason is simple arithmetic: $(n-k)+k=n$ for every $k=1,\ldots ,n-1$.

Comment: Thank you but I do feel you may have misunderstood my question - I tried to make it clear that I am aware that f: (x,y) -> (x+y) is not injective. That was my starting premise, not the answer I was seeking as a conclusion. When I say "why", I am asking more abstractly about if it is possible to have an operation like addition, but which is reversible. I am trying to understand if there is a number system where 1 + 3 != 2 + 2, but where these are unique and distinct. The problem then seems to be that if you are to keep the "ordering" integers have, you would need to figure out how

Comment: there could be a sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, but where 1 + 3 and 2 + 2 are different. Maybe there is a group like that... maybe "parallel" elements, in the ordering? Or maybe it can be proven that this is impossible? I want to know an operation that is close to, similar to addition, but bijective.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, it seems that you are looking for a pairing function, i.e. a bijective map $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. There are many examples, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Answer (score 1):

If you want 4, 1+3 and 2+2 to be separate elements of your collection, then you should also be able to involve these elements in sums separately. so 5+4, 5+(1+3), and 5+(2+2) should all be different elements of your structure as well.

Consider the set of expressions built up out of base elements via binary sums, with the trivial operation of addition being "add parentheses and stick a + sign between". So addition takes 5 and 4 as inputs and outputs 5+4 and addition takes 5 and 1+3 as inputs and outputs 5+(1+3).

This is a reasonable operation, but it's not associative (we view 5+(1+3) and (5+1)+3 as different expressions) and it doesn't have inverses, so it's not a group.

If you want a group, the operation on the one element group is bijective.

Comment: I think you're getting at what I was trying to understand, which is that if you want some operation *like* addition but which has this property that all sums are unique, it may be intrinsically impossible. Anything that acts *close* to addition is necessarily going to have this "overlapping" property. Any operation on a set that preserves uniqueness will necessarily lack certain core characteristics of integers. Is that correct, or, can you please elaborate on that, showing various subcases? What tweaks/modifications can we make to get structures with slightly different properties to "+"?

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication of prime numbers is reversible, in the sense that any positive integer is expressible as a product of primes in just one way (not counting changing order...).

(The computational difficulty of reversing the operation, that is, of *factoring* versus multiplying, is the basis of the RSA cryptosystem and other things...)